# VisualStateTrigger not updating

Tags: c#, xaml, visualstatemanager, visualstates, visualstategroup

I'm making an Universal Windows application. I'm using a `Splitview` for my menu and if I resize my window I use visual state triggers to adjust the layout. But it doesn't seem to be working.

I watched a lecture on the microsoft build site ([link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-679)).

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      DataContext="{StaticResource MainPageViewModel}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Min720State">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="SplitViewMenu.DisplayMode" Value="CompactInline" />
                    <Setter Target="SplitViewMenu.IsPaneOpen" Value="True" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Min320State">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="320" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="SplitViewMenu.DisplayMode" Value="CompactOverlay" />
                    <Setter Target="SplitViewMenu.IsPaneOpen" Value="False" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="DefaultState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="SplitViewMenu.DisplayMode" Value="Overlay" />
                    <Setter Target="SplitViewMenu.IsPaneOpen" Value="false" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="NavButton" Style="{StaticResource BtnNav}" Content="&#xE700;" Click="NavButton_Click" />
        <TextBlock Text="SoundCloud Plus" Style="{StaticResource AppTitle}" />
    </Grid>
    <SplitView x:Name="SplitViewMenu" Grid.Row="1" CompactPaneLength="48" IsPaneOpen="True" DisplayMode="CompactInline">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonsInMenu}" x:Name="AccountButton" Click="AccountButton_Click">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Width="36" Height="36" Source="/Assets/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextInMenu}" Grid.Column="1" Text="Connect with SoundCloud" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonsInMenu}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextInMenu}" Grid.Column="1" Text="Recent" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonsInMenu}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextInMenu}" Grid.Column="1" Text="Artists" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame x:Name="MyFrame"></Frame>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove IsPaneOpen="True" in your splitview